# Simulating Windows UI Desktop Start button feature

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

Greetings and salutation,

"just use Windows" is not the answer I am looking for, as I just decided to leave Windows for good and finally use Linux again. I use **Ubuntu Studio**, currently *Groovy Guerrilla*, and the windows manager is **xfce**. *slightly geeky, but fast and clean, and I want to user the standard*

My question is rather simple, yet I thought I would ask in openly, as the result might just be very useful for many.

Microsoft Windows has hung plenty of useful features on the Windows Key, a modifier key. My question thus relates what I now call the "start" modifier or start button.

I have manage to simulate some of the useful feature I use every day at work, but can for the life of me not figure out how to the windows(application) management the same way.

> How do I jump application windows from one screen to another using only the keyboard start and arrow buttons?

**For the hardcore Ubuntu users:**

---

Windows allow you to move, snap and hide  any application using this feature. The logic is if a window is **tiled**, the **left/right** arrow will snap it to half the current screen, the next arrow in the same direction, jumps to the next screen, if any. The **up** arrow maximize the app window, and **down** tiles it again, another **down** minimizes it to the task-bar.

---

What I have managed to do so far is to use **xfce4-keyboard-settings** and **xfwm4-settings** to setup some of the start+ (1,2,3...,E,D,P,S,L,left,right) functions, the jump feature however, is a conditional function binding, making it impossible to configure in these tools, or am I missing something.

Comment: Try other desktop environments.   KDE has many of these behaviors by default.

Comment: Yes, the Gnome desktop (with Mutter window manager) also has comparable features.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a [pending Xfce feature](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/issues/320) that hasn't been implemented yet, but these tools below provide a workaround for the time being.

https://github.com/jc00ke/move-to-next-monitor
http://ssokolow.com/quicktile/